# JavaFx savely stopping Background Task

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

right now I have a JavaFx program using a JavaFx Task inside a Thread as background process.

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>( ){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while(running){
            doSomething();
        }
        saveData();
        return null;
    }
};
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.start();
```

I would like to stop this process as smoothly as possible (meaning I would like to stop the process by setting running = false; and thus call the save() method whenever possible. At the same time I want to make sure that the background process has no chance to keep running after the JavaFx process (the window) was closed.

At the moment I am setting the Thread as a Deamon to make sure the process dies after the JavaFx process is dead (the two processes are the only ones running)

```
th.setDeamon(true);
```

At the same time I added a CloseRequestListener to my only Stage

```
stage.setOnCloseRequest( e -> running = false);
```

Now my Question:

Since the process is a Deamon, it can be removed in the middle of a run. Is there a better way to make sure the background task dies after the JavaFx process died? (even if the JavaFx process is forcefully killed)

Or is there a way to smoothly kill a deamon thread?

Edit: My main priority is that the background thread can't stay alive for itsself. And the second priority is that the background thread is killed as smoothly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) has a cancelation mechanism already, so there is no need to implement this yourself with the `running` flag (which you have to be careful to make `volatile`, or use other ways to make sure changes to it from one thread are visible in another).

So just do:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>( ){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while(! isCancelled()){
            doSomething();
        }
        saveData();
        return null;
    }
};
```

If your `doSomething()` method involves blocking calls that might throw `InterruptedException`s, be sure to catch the exception, as calling `cancel()` on the task will interrupt its thread:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>( ){
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while(! isCancelled()){
            try {
                doSomething();
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break ;
                }
            }
        } 

        saveData();
        return null;
    }
};
```

Finally, you should not rely on `setOnCloseRequest()` on your stage: this is only invoked if there is an *external* call to close the window (e.g. the user presses the native window close button). If you call `Platform.exit()`, for example, it will not get executed. Instead, override the `Application.stop()` method:

```
@Override
public void stop() {
    task.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you =) do you know if the stop() method will be called without exception? If I keep the thread as a deamon there is still the problem that it can be killed in the middle of doSomething(). Also as you mentioned the cancle() call can throw an interrupted exception which could break doSomething() halfway as well. I would like to prevent that as much as possible. If for example I change data, write it to multiple files and the process stops halfway, the data could get inpersistant.

Comment: That's only an issue if `doSomething()` has blocking calls that are interruptible. `stop()` will be called unless you exit with `System.exit()` (which just terminates all threads, so there's no possible way to work around that other than not calling it).